# How to get the topmost calling class/file name from a callee class

Tags: python, function

I have 3 classes -

1. ATest
2. BMain
3. CUtil

In `CUtil` I need the below functionality -

```
class CUtil(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("hi")
        if(topmost calling function is from ATest):
            print("ok")
        print("bye")
```

So the testcases would be like this -

1. From `ATest` creating `CUtil` object. Output - "hi ok bye"
2. From `BMAin` creating `CUtil` object. Output - "hi bye"
3. From `ATest` creating `BMain` object and from `BMain`'s constructor creating `CUtil` object. Output - "hi ok bye". Since the topmost calling class is `ATest`
4. From `BMain` creating `ATest` object and from `ATest`'s constructor creating `CUtil` object. Output - "hi bye". Since the topmost calling class is `BMain`

Is there anyway I can get the functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
stack = inspect.stack()
the_class = stack[1][0].f_locals["self"].__class__
```

Comment: It's working if called from a class. But getting a KeyError on "self" when called from a single module script not from a class. Which is expected from the current code you gave. Can this be solved?